# Unable to boot Windows after installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows, startup, uefi

I have a Windows 8 Computer with UEFI. Here is how I tried to install Ubuntu:

• Disabled Secure Boot, loaded live USB with 12.10 x64

• Created 30.0GB partition in Windows for Ubuntu

• Installed Ubuntu

• DURING INSTALLATION: The wizard asked me if I wanted to create a swap partition. I was told by a previous guide not to use the wizard partition manager, but I thought creating a swap would be a good idea. So I made a with 500MB swap partition.

After installation, I installed boot repair.

Now Grub starts up perfectly fine on startup, but when selecting Windows 8, I only come to a HP Boot Repair screen, which is futile. So here are my problems:

• I cannot access the partition with my Windows 8 files through the HP backup software partition.

• I cannot boot into Windows 8.

• I cannot access the Windows 8 partition through Ubuntu to rescue my files.

I believe it is because I created a swap partition, and now I am stuck. Formatting my hard drive is my last resort. I AT LEAST want to backup my files from my Windows 8 partition.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the HP Boot Repair screen. Repair the Windows installation. This should repair the Windows bootloader, you may need to repeat the Grub Repair after this has been done, but it should only be that file that's been corrupted.

Comment: Last time, the repair was automatic so I wasn't able to choose Windows or Ubuntu to be repaired. I'll try messing around with it one more time.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems like my entire Windows partition has been converted to swap. I am horrified, but that's life I guess.

Comment: That's a pain. Hope you are able to rescue the data